# serve multiple gunicorn django instances under nginx ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I need to serve up two webs apps (Django) on gunicorn under different domain names using nginx on ubuntu. I started using this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

It worked just fine for one using that. Then I tried to do the same thing for the second but it gives me a 502 gateway for the second domain. So I tried following this tutorial:
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/

I'm at the part where you run the gunicorn start script:

```
sudo bin/gunicorn_start
```

I get back the response:

```
Starting webuildblack as root
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/devin/webuildblack/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
            from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
                ImportError: No module named 'gunicorn.app'; 'gunicorn' is not a package
```

Comment: you should check `502 gateway` problem first. You could check nginx logs and run django in debug mode to see more information about problem. Sometimes it can be simple problem like problem with database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have named your program `gunicorn.py` like the `gunicorn`-package. Rename your this file and remove any `gunicorn.pyc` file.

Comment: scratch that you were right. I tried that again and it worked after I deleted the pyc file. thank you!